# OpenSSH keys file cannot be UTF-16 formatted - prev: Windows (10) OpenSSH (Microsoft's flavour) refuses to accept all popular Public Key Algorithms

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, openssh, public-key

I have been trying to setup an OpenSSH server on Windows 10.

The issue is with the Public Keys, password auth works fine.

The file permissions for both normal and administrative users are not the problem - they are setup properly. The server does not accept the keys for any kind of user, I have first tried my regular `ssh-rsa` key, then `ecdsa-sha2-nistp521`, and `ssh-ed25519` - all failed.

If the package origins matters for anyone, I've used the `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0` PowerShell command.

The log is from my last attempt, but for all of the key algorithms error is the same, just the algorithm name / key values/hashes changes.

```
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 284
debug2: parse_server_config: config __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config len 284
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:34 setting PubkeyAuthentication yes
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:38 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:78 setting Subsystem sftp sftp-server.exe
debug3: checking syntax for 'Match Group administrators'
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:<host-key-hash-1>
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:<host-key-hash-2>
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:<host-key-hash-3>
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-ddd'
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 3 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 284
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
Connection from <client-ipv4> port 34468 on <server-ipv4> port 22
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_9.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: spawning "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe" -ddd -y
debug2: Network child is on pid 6384
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 4 config len 284
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: recv_rexec_state: entering fd = 3
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug3: recv_rexec_state: done
debug2: parse_server_config: config __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config len 284
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:34 setting PubkeyAuthentication yes
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:38 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:78 setting Subsystem sftp sftp-server.exe
debug3: checking syntax for 'Match Group administrators'
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: recv_hostkeys_state: entering fd = 3
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug3: recv_hostkeys_state: done
debug3: recv_idexch_state: entering fd = 3
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug3: recv_idexch_state: done
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: KEX signature <idk-what-that-is>(83)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 7 [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user <username> service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 284
debug3: checking match for 'Group administrators' user <username> host <client-ipv4> addr <client-ipv4> laddr <server-ipv4> lport 22
debug3: get_user_token - i am running as <username>, returning process token
debug1: user <username> matched group list administrators at line 92
debug3: match found
debug3: reprocess config:93 setting AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for <username> [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 12.988ms, delaying 4.193ms (requested 8.590ms) [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user <username> service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
debug2: userauth_pubkey: valid user <username> querying public key ssh-ed25519 <the-user-key-base64> [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg ssh-ed25519 pkblob ED25519 SHA256:<appropriate-hash-for-the-user-key-from-above> [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: <idk-what-that-is>
debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
debug2: __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys:1: check options: '\377\376s'
debug2: __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys:1: advance: ''
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: ED25519 key is not allowed
Failed publickey for <username> from <client-ipv4> port 34468 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:<appropriate-hash-for-the-user-key-from-above>
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 8.998ms, delaying 8.183ms (requested 8.590ms) [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
Connection closed by authenticating user <username> <client-ipv4> port 34468 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 6384
```

I do not believe that this whole log is necessary, but I will not refuse help from any of the '*You must post the whole log, if you expect MY help*' people.

I suspect that the `ED25519 key is not allowed` is most important. The key algorithm name changes whenever I change the key inside `<user-home-dir>/.ssh/authorized_keys` or the `(...)/administrators_authorized_keys` files to match the used key's algorithm.

I don't know why Windows' OpenSSH does not like any of my keys.

Answer (score 4):

The keys are not the problem.

I have used the `echo '<key>' > <key-file>` PowerShell command to copy the public key, the created file text format was `UTF-16 LE` which I have not figured out until I started to think what's with the `debug2: __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys:1: check options: '\377\376s'` line, just now.

Although the log was not very verbose about the file encoding / unexpected bytes in ASCII text file being the problem...

**If you have similar weird problem check your file encoding!**

*I promise I was trying to figure this out multiple hours before posting this, just... posting it somehow helped me figure this out...*

Comment: glad you got it working. yes I believe that key bytes are always expressing ASCII characters, so if you are converting from char>byte, stick to ASCII.

Comment: OMG!!! This was my problem too! And here I thought `check options: 'ÿþs'` was just informing me about some fancy 'ÿþs' options. Save `authorized_keys` as UTF-8 and it works fine. I think the blame for this goes to the "improved" version of Notepad on Windows 11. (Note to rest of world: you will not see these messages without `LogLevel Debug3` in `\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config`.)